# Replace portions of a list with another in Prolog

Tags: replace, prolog, substitution

I want to replace `b,c` with `x,y,z` in a list in Prolog. I have a list `[a,b,c,d,e,f]` and result will be `[a,x,y,z,d,e,f]`. How can I write this in Prolog?

```
replace([],_,[]).
replace([x|T1],Var,[Y|T2]):-
      member(X=Y,var),
      !
   ;  X=Y
   ),
   replace(T1,Var,T2).

-? replace([a,b,c,d,e,f],[b,c=x,y,z],R).
```

Comment: You have typographical errors in your program. Also, try `write_canonical([b,c=x,y,z])`. Prolog doesn't see this term the way you think it does. Written in list notation, it's treated as: `[b, =(c,x), y, z]`. What if `b,c` occurs more than once in your list? Do all occurrences need to be replaced?

Comment: Here's a hint: think about how you can use `append/3 to` determine whether a list `P` is the prefix of list `L`.

Comment: your query should be `replace([a,b,c,d,e,f], [b,c], [x,y,z], R).` It is you the programmer which assigns the meaning to this predicate's arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially equivalent to the problem of [replacing substrings in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49745481/replacing-substrings-in-prolog). Using the [`replace_substring/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49761025/975097) predicate, you can replace a subsequence of the list in this way:

```
:- initialization(main).
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars). 

main :-
    replace_substring([a,b,c,d,e,f],[b,c],[x,y,z],Result),
    writeln(Result).

replace_substring(String, To_Replace, Replace_With, Result) :-
    append([Front, To_Replace, Back], String),
    append([Front, Replace_With, Back], Result).
```

This program prints `[a,x,y,z,d,e,f]`.