# Replacing substrings in Prolog

Tags: replace, prolog

In order to replace a substring in a string, I wrote a predicate called `replace_substring`. It uses SWI-Prolog's [append/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3) predicate:

```
:- initialization(main).
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars). 

main :-
    replace_substring("this is a string","string","replaced string",Result),
    writeln(Result).

replace_substring(String,To_Replace,Replace_With,Result) :-
    append(First,To_Replace,String),
    append(First,Replace_With,Result).
```

Still, I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to replace substrings in Prolog. Does Prolog have a built-in predicate that could be used for the same purpose?

Comment: What do you expect for `replace_substring("aa","a","b", R)`?

Comment: `replace_substring("abc", "bc", "23", R).` will succeed, but `replace_substring("abc", "b", "2", R).` will fail since your implementation only succeeds if the substring being replaced is a suffix of the original string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, no, Prolog does not have a built-in string replace predicate. What you show will only replace the substring if that substring is at the end of the original string. That is, it will replace `"abc"` in the string `"xyzabc"` but not in the string `"xyabcz"`.

You can use `append/2`:

```
replace_substring(String, To_Replace, Replace_With, Result) :-
    append([Front, To_Replace, Back], String),
    append([Front, Replace_With, Back], Result).
```

If you want it to succeed without replacing on a non-match, then:

```
replace_substring(String, To_Replace, Replace_With, Result) :-
    (    append([Front, To_Replace, Back], String)
    ->   append([Front, Replace_With, Back], Result)
    ;    Result = String
    ).
```

As @false hints in his question, do you want to handle replacing multiple occurrences? If so, the extension to your method would be:

```
replace_substring(String, To_Replace, Replace_With, Result) :-
    (    append([Front, To_Replace, Back], String)
    ->   append([Front, Replace_With, Back], R),
         replace_substring(Back, To_Replace, Replace_With, Result)
    ;    Result = String
    ).
```

Comment: This `->` making all of it non-relational ...